# I want Change My Storage Path in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, cdn

My All Uploading Files Are saved in Project/Storage/App

But I want to save in cdn.myproject.com/files/

How i can do it please guide me

Thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#configuration . You can store files anywhere you want, you just need to configure it properly and use the right methods.

Comment: Please follow screenshoot below https://prnt.sc/mdUO-1ZANWRK

Comment: This does not make sense, you compare a path and a url

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow aditya! please take a [tour] and learn [ask]. can you elaborate where is this `cdn.myproject.com/files` located relative to your laravel app? what it runs on? aws or something else? laravel is pretty extensible, you can add your own storage provider. however as the others have pointed out, your question is very vague at best.

Answer (score 1):

The Default Filesystem Disk is defined in /config/filesystems.php.  The entry looks like this:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),
```

You may, or may not, have an entry in the .env file for FILESYSTEM_DISK.  If not, the default value in this example is set to 'local'.  'local' is defined further down the filesystems.php file and looks like this:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
    'throw' => false,
],
```

Change you default filesystem disk to 'public' (either in the .env file or in filesystems.php).  The default 'public' config should like to this:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'throw' => false,
],
```

As you see above Laravel wants to store your files within the storage path.  Since this is a "non-public" directory, you have have to use 'php artisan' to create a symbolic link from this location to a location in the public directory.  Use this command:

```
$ php artisan storage:link
```

Lastly, you can store your images within a /files directory by specifying it:

$attributes['newfile'] = request()->file('newfile')->store('files');

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change your entire storage path, or just the uploaded path?

To change storage/ path: in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider` `register()` method, add the following line:

```php
$this->app->useStoragePath('/path/to/your/storage/directory/');
```

If you want to change just the upload directory, follow [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads) documentation